# matlab evaluates 0.9<0.9 to `True`

Tags: matlab

Below is my matlab code snippet:

```
clear all;
x0=0.5;
x2=1.4;
h=0.1;
while(x0<x2)
    x0=x0+0.1;
end
x0
```

There is no doubt that the result of `x0` is  `1.4`, what confused me is when I replace `x2=1.4` to `x2=0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2`(anyone of them) the result becomes incorrect.

For example, `x2=0.9` will makes the code generate `x0=1.0` instead of `x0=0.9`. And I find the fact that during the process with `x0` increases to `0.9` then `x0<x2`(`0.9<0.9`) will yeild `1`(True) which is definitely wrong.

What's going on here?

Comment: "And I find the fact that during the process with x0 increases to 0.9 then x0<x2(0.9<0.9) "....How did you conclude this?

Comment: @apomene I output x0, x2 and x0<x2 in the loop, here I omit these sentences

Comment: once again, one of the most popular questions appears.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to extend Dan's answer a little. Run this code:

```
clear all;
x0=0.5;
x2=0.9;
h=0.1;
while(x0<x2)
    x0=x0+0.1;
    disp(x2-x0); % <-- I added this line
end
x0
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/phpkwE)):

```
0.30000
0.20000
0.10000
1.1102e-16
-0.100000
x0 =  1.00000
```

The 4th line of the output shows the rounding error: after adding `0.1` to `0.5` four times, the result will be less than `0.9`: the difference is `1.1102e-16`. That's why `x0` will be `1.0` in the end.

Comment: Great example, very illustrative.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you should never compare floating point numbers directly. [See this link](http://floating-point-gui.de/) provided by Sam Roberts to better understand this.

In binary, 0.1 becomes a recurring decimal which your computer eventually has to truncate. So you aren't really adding 0.1 and that rounding error compounds each time you add 0.1 eventually leading to your comparison missing. So you are not actually evaluating 0.9<0.9 but rather the sum of a truncated conversion to binary of 0.1 9 times with the truncated binary version of 0.9. The numbers won't be the same.

Comment: @SamRoberts Great site, I must remember it! Amended the link in my answer to point there instead.

Comment: Got it, what is the general way to compare float numbers，for this problem , using `abs`?

Comment: Something like `while(x0-x2 < eps)`. `x0-x2` is the same as `x0-x2<0` right, so just replace the 0 with a tiny positive number (like `eps`) to account for those rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need to compare floating point values, I would suggest doing it a little differently. You can do something similar to what is written below; where `threshold`  is some acceptable margin that is the numbers different by this amount they are considered different, and if the difference is less than this amount, they are considered to be the same.

```
function result = floatCompare(a,b,operation,threshold)
    if nargin < 4
        threshold = eps;
    end
    if nargin < 3
        operation = 'eq';
    end
    switch operation
        case 'eq'
            disp('equals')
            result = abs(a-b) < threshold;
        case 'lt'
            disp('less than')
            result = b-a > threshold;
        case 'gt'
            disp('greater than')
            result = a-b > threshold;
    end
end
```